# Install MFTF Automation testing in Magento Version 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, testing, code, mftf, selenium

I am trying to install MFTF automation testing in Magento's latest version 2.4. I am following the Magento basic documentation. In the Magento root directory, I run the command `vendor/bin/mftf build: project` in the directory path `vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework` it is showing an issue.
[image]
it is not creating a folder MFTF inside the bin folder of the Vendor.

Then I tried to follow the link https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/a-quick-guide-to-automation-test-in-magento-2/ but it is the old Magento version.

Can you please tell me from which location I have to run the command `vendor/bin/mftf build: project` to add MFTF to the website?

Comment: Please help me to add Automation testing in Magento 2.4 version

Comment: Is it a typo: space between the `build:` and `project` in your command `vendor/bin/mftf build: project`? You must run this command from the Magento root directory with Magento owner permissions (usually it is `www-data`).